# Force Unreal Engine to use opengl on windows executable

Tags: opengl, directx, unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to make a video game in Unreal Engine 4.9. I'm building it for Windows, but I'd like to have it use opengl instead of directx in the executable. However, I've found no options that let you do this. Unreal Engine uses OpenGL when it creates executables for Linux and Mac, but there seems to be no way to use OpenGL with Windows.

Am I missing something? Is there some way to force Unreal Engine to use OpenGL in Windows executables?

EDIT: The reason I want to use OpenGL is because I want this game to run without having to install anything on the end user's computer (DirectX has to be installed to work)

Comment: I do not agree that this questions deserves a vote-down, I am asking every-one to try to help rather than playing with the arrows vote+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't really support OpenGL, they typically go out of their way to make it very difficult to use OpenGL on Windows and strongly encourage people to use DirectX instead.

The simplest way to get a working OpenGL context in windows is sometimes to use ANGLE which is a compatibility layer which translates OpenGL calls to DirectX calls. This is what Chrome and Firefox use to support WebGL on windows. I doubt that Unreal Engine is integrated with this, so you might have a hard time.

Edit:

> EDIT: The reason I want to use OpenGL is because I want this game to run without having to install anything on the end user's computer (DirectX has to be installed to work)

One thing you could do is cross-compile the Mesa3D drivers, as described here: https://wiki.qt.io/Cross_compiling_Mesa_for_Windows

But then you won't get hardware acceleration.